# Creating anchor tag from rel attribute

Tags: jquery

I am just about jQuery and attr rel usage.

I do not understand why this code is not working

`$(".html5").append('<a target="_blank" href="'+ $(this).attr('rel') +'"></a>');`

and following one is ok

`$(".html5").append('<a target="_blank" href="'+ $(".html5").attr('rel') +'"></a>');`

I just want to get rel atribute from html5 class and put this rel attribute to created anchor tag.There will be more classes with own rel like `$(".html5, .css3, .js")`, that is why I want to use $(this)

Comment: Maybe you have to use `this` instead of `$("this")`, because `this` is already the JQuery extended object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .each(...) feature of jQuery where it loops all elements and runs some code for each item. For example:

```
$(".html5").each(function(index,item) {
    var jItem = $(item);
    jItem.append('<a target="_blank" href="' + jItem.attr('rel') + '"></a>');
});
```